# SQL: SUM in the middle of a SELECT query fails

Tags: sql, join, group-by

I have the following tables:

**Invoice**

- InvoiceID
- CompanyName

**InvoiceLine**

- InvoiceLineID
- InvoiceID
- Amount

I want to have the following: The company name and total amount of invoice with ID 1760.

I use the following query:

```
SELECT i.*, sum(il.amount) as 'Total' 
FROM invoice i JOIN invoiceLine il on  i.invoiceID = il.InvoiceID 
WHERE i.InvoiceID = 1760
```

I get this as error:

> Column 'invoice.invoiceID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Why is the error returned and why does it want me to use a GROUP BY clause while i'm only expecting one row to be returned? Would I be obligated to do this in 2 queries?

Comment: change this i.invoiceID to i.InvoiceID     capital I. and let me know what happens ?

Comment: doesnt solve it, i have the exact same if i use `i.*, SUM(il.amount)`

Comment: you use same case letter as in the table columns fields , you done mistakes in full query , please check it.

Answer (score 2):

You will need a GROUP BY for each column that you are not aggregating

Try this:

```
SELECT i.invoiceID, i.companyName, sum(il.amount) as 'Total' 
FROM invoice i JOIN invoiceLine il on  i.invoiceID = il.InvoiceID 
WHERE i.InvoiceID = 1760
GROUP BY i.invoiceID, i.companyName
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify columns to group by when performing aggregate functions.

```
SELECT i.InvoiceID,i.CompanyName, sum(il.amount) as 'Total' 
FROM invoice i JOIN invoiceLine il on  i.invoiceID = il.InvoiceID 
WHERE i.InvoiceID = 1760
group by i.InvoiceID,i.CompanyName
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT i.*,
       (SELCT sum(il.amount)
        FROM invoiceLine il 
        WHERE i.invoiceID = il.InvoiceID
       ) as Total
FROM invoice i 
WHERE i.InvoiceID = 1760;
```